# Bug in QAT for Published Add-In?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

It is very frustrating that you can't make Word Add-ins persistent yet...

Next best is adding commands to the QAT (Word Quick Access Toolbar).

But when I add my Add-in, while it looks like it will work, the QAT does not update with my button(s). No error is thrown...

Known issue by Microsoft?

[image: Screenshot of QAT and Published Add-in]

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what you mean by "not persistent"? If you mean auto-opening a pane, take a look at this article: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/tree/master/AutoOpenTaskpane  As for the QAT on the Mac, yes, it is a known issue that add-in commands don't work properly there yet, it in our backlog.

Comment: Thank you for reading, Humberto...and for clarifying that the issue is in backlog.

I also appreciate that you commented on my 'persistent' comment...

I read through the link you provided, and it makes perfect sense. But my use case is teachers, and so they're most likely going to open 100 documents once. So flagging a document to be persistent doesn't help; they would want my taskpane to stay open for an extended grading session - for every doc they open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the QAT/customization on the MAC is a known issue that is in our backlog. I don't have an ETA to share at the moment. As for the ability to auto-open a taskpane with every document, we don't support that. Please open a suggestion/vote on uservoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Side note: As I mentioned on the comments, we do support this https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/tree/master/AutoOpenTaskpane even though it might not help in your case.